# DMN model to get rule data

Tags: spring-boot, dmn

I am using Decision model notation(DMN) rule table locally (not deployed in development server) in my spring boot project. To get the the rule service output data, how to integrate rule services in my project serviceImpl class? can someone help me, or give me the steps/code to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kogito with Spring Boot as shown [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4q694kP7jbY), and then use one of the available code [generated REST API](https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single/#ref-rest-dmn-endpoints_kogito-dmn-models) as a starting point to customize your classes.

Alternatively, you may opt to use the "[Kogito incubation API](https://blog.kie.org/2021/11/the-road-towards-a-kogito-public-api.html)" to fully implement your code using the Drools DMN Engine inside of Kogito (again, on top of Spring Boot)